# Convert numpy array to RTSP stream

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, opencv, python

I have stream of numpy arrays on input and then using OpenCV I am converting it into jpgs. Then I am streaming jpegs to the browser with multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame mimetype. Everything runs on local machine.

I want to replace jpg stream with Rtsp stream. Which libs/tools/tech stack should I use?

Comment: Web browsers do not have support for RTSP.

Comment: Web browsers don't support RTSP streams, but they support HLS (stands for HTML5 Live Stream or something like that, not really sure). You can convert your jpegs into a single h264 video and then create a HLS stream from this video. But this is only if you insist on having a bunch of JPEGs. Alternatively, if your camera supports RTSP (most probably on port 554, if it's an IP camera) you can convert the RTSP to HLS using ffmpeg.